# Separate structs in C

Tags: c

Since I am quite new to C I would be grateful if someone takes a look at my code.
I found this program on internet and I want to improve it to what I want so that I learn some basic C coding. The program has 4 options (add, list, delete and Exit). Its maybe to much I am asking but again grateful for ur help.

What I want:

I want to have two separate structs where one belongs to an owner which contains name and age and the second to a vehicle which contains owner name, plate and car brand. But both should be connected to each and get data from user and when I press 2(list) it should print out all info about both owner and the vehicle.

I want the program to create an array for ten vehicles and a function to list all data about vehicle registered in file.

Again its not my code and I am quite new to C. Appreciate your answers to be for a beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h> ///for input output functions like printf, scanf
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  ///string operations

/** List of Global Variable */


/**
    function : gotoxy
    @param input: x and y coordinates
    @param output: moves the cursor in specified position of console
*/


/** Main function started */
int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *ft; /// file pointers
    char another, choice;

    /** structure that represent a owner */
    struct emp
    {
        char name[40]; ///name of owner
        int age; /// age of age of owner
        char brand[40]; //brand
        char plate [6];

        
    };

    struct emp e; /// structure variable creation

    char empname[40]; /// string to store name of the owner

    long int recsize; /// size of each record of owner

    /** open the file in binary read and write mode
    * if the file EMP.DAT already exists then it open that file in read write mode
    * if the file doesn't exit it simply create a new copy
    */
    fp = fopen("EMP.h","rb+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fp = fopen("EMP.h","wb+");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Cannot open file");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /// sizeo of each record i.e. size of structure variable e
    recsize = sizeof(e);

    /// infinite loop continues untile the break statement encounter
    while(1)
    {
        system("clear"); ///clear the console window
       /// move the cursor to postion 30, 10 from top-left corner
        printf("\n1. Add Record\n"); /// option for add record

        printf("\n2. List Records\n"); /// option for showing existing record
        
        printf("\n3. Delete Records\n"); /// option for deleting record
     
        printf("\n4. Exit\n"); /// exit from the program
       
        printf("Your Choice: "); /// enter the choice 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        fflush(stdin); /// flush the input buffer
        choice  = getchar(); /// get the input from keyboard
        switch(choice)
        {
        case '1':  /// if user press 1
            system("clear");
            fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); /// search the file and move cursor to end of the file
            /// here 0 indicates moving 0 distance from the end of the file

            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')  /// if user want to add another record
            {
                printf("\nEnter name: ");
                scanf("%s",e.name);
                printf("\nEnter age: ");
                scanf("%d", &e.age);
                printf("\nVehicle brand: ");
                scanf("%s",e.brand);
                printf("\nplate: ");
                scanf("%s",e.plate);
                

                fwrite(&e,recsize,1,fp); /// write the record in the file

                printf("\nAdd another record(y/n) ");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getchar();
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            system("clear");
            rewind(fp); ///this moves file cursor to start of the file
            while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp)==1)  /// read the file and fetch the record one record per fetch
            {
                printf("\n Name: %s age: %d brand: %s plate: %s",e.name,e.age,e.brand, e.plate); /// 
            }
            getchar();
            break;

        
        case '3':
            system("clear");
            another = 'y';
            while(another == 'y')
            {
                printf("\nEnter name of owner the car to delete: ");
                scanf("%s",empname);
                ft = fopen("Temp.dat","wb");  /// create a intermediate file for temporary storage
                rewind(fp); /// move record to starting of file
                while(fread(&e,recsize,1,fp) == 1)  /// read all records from file
                {
                    if(strcmp(e.name,empname) != 0)  /// if the entered record match
                    {
                        fwrite(&e,recsize,1,ft); /// move all records except the one that is to be deleted to temp file
                    }
                }
                fclose(fp);
                fclose(ft);
                remove("EMP.DAT"); /// remove the orginal file
                rename("Temp.dat","EMP.DAT"); /// rename the temp file to original file name
                fp = fopen("EMP.DAT", "rb+");
                printf("Delete another record(y/n)");
                fflush(stdin);
                another = getchar();
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            fclose(fp);  /// close the file
            exit(0); /// exit from the program
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define

```
typedef struct car{

 char brand[40];
 // write here every car attribute you want

}car;
```

and then the person

```
typedef struct owner{
  char name[40];
  int age;
  car *car;
}owner;
```

and then you print it with

```
 printf("Name: %s age: %d brand: %s ",owner.name,owner.age,owner.car->brand);
```

Comment: Tried but when it comes to car it says Segmentation fault (core dumped). I know its about storing data and stuff but no idea how to fix.

Comment: `car car;`  and `owner owner;`  and then `owner.car = &car;`